# SQLLocalDb not recognised but connecting to SSMS

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssms

I installed SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) V18.0 and SQL LocalDB 2016 on my PC.
I can successfully connect to the server using below in SSMS.

> (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB

I created a database and a simple table with one field using SSMS.
Using VB.Net, i can connect and read the data from the server using the connection string of

> Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=C:\TestDB\mydb.mdf;

When i try to view the instance running using command prompt, i try to use below

> sqllocaldb info

When i enter above, i get the following:

> C:\Users\User>sqllocaldb info
>   'sqllocaldb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Am i missing something to cause this error?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

In your vb.net code, if you want to call the SQL connection, firstly you need to make sure you import SQL client module.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```